# Apache webserver and apache tomcat on port 80 - configuration

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, webserver

I have a dedicated webserver on which I will host only one website via apache tomcat.
My Problem: I cant dissable apache webserver and run tomcat on port 80 because the domain need the webserver. Otherwise the domains dont work.

So Im looking for a easy to configure way to run apache webserver and apache tomcat, so that I can use the website on tomcat with port 80 in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

Only one process can take port 80. In your case it seems Apache (web server) should be the one. You cannot configure Tomcat to use the same port.

An alternative would be to configure Apache to work as a reverse proxy for a specific ***location***. For instance, make all requests going to /myapp to be routed or bridged to Tomcat which would be running on a different port.

The directives would be something similar to:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
...
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8080
...
<Location "/myapp">
  # Allow access to this proxied URL location for everyone.
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

Where tomcat would be running in port 8080, your context is /myapp and your system is running on Linux.

Check this URL for a more detailed example: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy

Comment: Thx, that looks like a perfect solution but it doesnt work. I did it like in your link (with webapps). When i call the domain i got the parallels startpage from the apache webserver. when i call the domain with :8080 I got my homepage from the apache tomcat server. But when i call the domain/webapps i just got a blank page (NOT a 404 not found page, just blank).
What is wrong?

Comment: webapps is just an example. You need to change it according to your situation. What's the context you are using on tomcat for your application? I would think using the location with the same name will require simpler configuration.

Comment: the code does something. when your code is not in the config, url.de/myapp is not found, but when your code is in the config, then url.de/myapp is a blank page. But url.de:8080 is also a blank page, so the Problem is maybe something else?

Comment: ok i dont get it. is here someone or can advise me someone who has experience with this stuff and could help me for some bucks? (maybe with skype)

Comment: Check the apache logs and the logs from tomcat to see the request generated in Apache and the request received in Tomcat.

Comment: @user3876178 Marcelo's answer is the canonical way to use tomcat behind a Apache Http server reverse proxy. But *you* have now to read the docs, try, and ask another question if you have a precise problem.